# Server initialization incognita

Tags: python, server

I am trying to initialize a local server on Python.
How is possible that the server initialization that I show on the image below is working?

Funny enough, `app.run` is not crushing the program. I was expecting some error of the kind: `"app" does not have any run method` or `"app" has not been defined` or something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

If you put your imports before you initialize and run app. It should pull in everything correctly and work.

Comment: Exactly, @mkamerath, that is what I was expecting, but the code does actually work, and thus my question.

Comment: When running your script with python36, I got the error name "app" is not defined

Comment: Yes, I just found the same. It was working the whole time, but now it doesn't (good notice.. it didn't make any sense otherwise). I guess I might have had some overwrited variable or somethign... Thanks for the comments anyway. It feels like a stupid question now, but I guess I can't delete it.